# Optimizing upper and lower bounds

Tags: reference-request, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

Let $L_i:X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be continuous (objective) functions defined on a metric space $X$ and suppose that
$$
L_1(x)\leq L_2(x)\leq L_3(x)\qquad (\forall x \in X).
$$
Here, I imagine that $L_2$ is challenging to evaluate numerically but somehow $L_1$ and $L_3$ are simpler.  Is there a studied method for relaxing the optimization of $L_2$ using $L_1$ and $L_3$?

For example, I am thinking of optimizing instead $L(x):= L_3(x) + |L_3(x) - L_1(x)|$ or $\tilde{L}(x):= L_1(x) + |L_3(x)- L_1(x)|^2$... but there are many options and I do not know if there is a "best" or "standard" approach...

Comment: There is not enough information here to select a best approach. Do you need the optimum location of $x$ or is it enough to know the optimum value of $L_2(x)$? What else are you going to do with the optimum?

Comment: For the moment, it okay to find the optimal value only.  What do you mean by "what else are you ...)?

Comment: If $L_3,L_1$ are convex then can we say more?  (as a warmup)

Comment: Let $L_2^*$ be the (unknown) optimal objective value of $L_2$.

Use a numerical global optimizer to find the optimal objective value $L_1^*$ of $L_1$, and the optimal objective value $L_3^*$ of $L_3$.

Then you can conclude that  $L_1^* \le L_2^* \le  L_3^*$.  If $L1$ and $L_3$ are convex, then presuming this is a minimization problem, the global optimizations of $L1$ and $L_3$  will be "easy", and a local numerical minimizxer can be used to find the global minima, or perhaps specialized conic solvers can be used, depending on $L1, L_3$  and the constraints.